# Obtain callgraph for pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to obtain the callgraph data for the methods provided by [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) and [numpy](https://numpy.org/). For this particular use case, visualization is not necessary.

So far I've tried [PyCG](https://github.com/vitsalis/PyCG) and [pycallgraph2](https://github.com/daneads/pycallgraph2). Both of these packages work well when I analyze small packages.

When I try to apply those on the large
packages like `pandas` or `numpy`, it starts processing but there is no output. It consumes `cpu`, `ram` and `swap` so I know for sure that it's working. But it never finishes the processing. I've cross-checked by running `pycg` with `strace`, I can see all of the `syscalls` it's making.

In about three hours I run out of memory and can't obtain any usable output (specifically for `numpy` and `pandas`).

for `pycg`:

I executed

```bash
cd $PYVENV/lib64/python3.11/site-packages 
strace pycg --package pandas $(find pandas -type f -name "*.py") -o pandas.json
```

Is there any other/better way to do this?
Thanks!